# Is Mathematica really integrating something?

Tags: numerical-integration

I have a recursive method to get a function, which is already working in other programs, so everything is alright with the method. My problem is when I try to integrate `cond[wr]` in some limit, like `{wr, -1, 1}`, it takes so long and I get not from this.

Can you tell me why this NIntegrate is not working?

```
NIntegrate[cond[wr], {wr, -1, 1}]
```

Where `cond[wr]` is obtained from: https://pastebin.com/d5zbYfnH

Comment: I think the problem is simple: Maybe your code is just awfully inefficient. Is see lines like `Subscript[b, i] = ...` involving `Inverse` on the right hand side. That somehow tells me, that you might  invert the same matrices multiple times. In particular, I found this at _several_ places: `Inverse[Energy - H - \[CapitalAlpha] - \[CapitalBeta] - Subscript[CC, i - 1]]`. So, I suggest to remove the redundant computations first in order to make your function `cond` more efficient.

Comment: Moreover, using `LinearSolve` instead of `Inverse` should be faster and more accurate. With `Inverse`, you are likely having numerical instabilities that leads to errors that are more or less randomly distributed. And that might also hinder `NIntegrate` from converging: `NIntergrate` supposes that the integrand is more or less smooth; but it has a hard time to deal with a function with basically random function values.

Comment: In which way I could write the coeficients "Subscript[b, i] " in therms of LinearSolve?

Comment: Hey @HenrikSchumacher, first of all I would like to than you again for the help, I'm using this code until today. Besides that one of things that I've lost in comparison with my last code is that G0 and G2 are sharing the same H with G11, however, sometimes I need to use a H0 and H2 different from H. Also define a different U, more like U0,11 (to connect H0 with H) and U11,2 (to connect H with H2) thinking in a system with the sequence like this H0 | H | H2.

Comment: Said that, I'm having problems to implement this sort of change in your suggested code. Here is an example of one innefficient old code that I've done pastebin.com/k2wvfkLj using a system with the sequence 0 | 1 | 2 (for the zigzag case k=2). I was wondering that I just need to double the process for both H0 and H2 because H is not used in the LinearSolve process.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Code Refactoring

This is the part that I did not touch, since it is decently efficient and is called only once:

```
getPandH[wr_] := 
  Module[{n = 7, s = 20, η = 10^-3, ϵ = 0, t = 2.75, U, HH, Energy, L},
   If[OddQ[n], L = (n - 1)/2;
    U = DiagonalMatrix[Flatten[{0, t, 0, Table[{0, 0, 0, t, 0, 0, 0, t}, {i, 1, L}]}], -3];
    HH = DiagonalMatrix[Flatten[{ϵ, ϵ, ϵ, ϵ, ϵ, ϵ,Table[{ϵ, ϵ, ϵ, ϵ, ϵ, ϵ, ϵ, ϵ}, {i, 1, L}]}], 0] 
      + DiagonalMatrix[Flatten[{t, t, t, t, t, Table[{0, t, t, t, 0, t, t, t}, {i, 1, L}]}], 1] 
      + DiagonalMatrix[Flatten[{0, 0, 0, Table[{0, 0, 0, 0, t, 0, 0, 0}, {i, 1, L}]}], 3] 
      + DiagonalMatrix[Flatten[{0, 0, Table[{t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {i, 1, L}]}], 4] 
      + DiagonalMatrix[Flatten[{t, Table[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, t}, {i, 1, L}]}], 5] + 
      If[n == 1, 0, 
       DiagonalMatrix[
        Flatten[Table[{0, 0, 0, t, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {i, 1, L}]], 6]];
    Energy = (wr + I*η)*
      DiagonalMatrix[
       Flatten[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
         Table[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {i, 1, L}]}], 0];, L = n/2;
    U = DiagonalMatrix[
      Flatten[{0, t, 0, 0, 0, 0, t, 
        Table[{0, 0, 0, t, 0, 0, 0, t}, {i, 1, L - 1}]}], -3];
    HH = DiagonalMatrix[
       Flatten[{ϵ, ϵ, ϵ, ϵ, ϵ, ϵ, ϵ, ϵ, ϵ, ϵ, 
         Table[{ϵ, ϵ, ϵ, ϵ, ϵ, ϵ, ϵ, ϵ}, {i, 1, L - 1}]}], 
       0] + DiagonalMatrix[
       Flatten[{t, t, t, t, t, 0, t, t, t, 
         Table[{0, t, t, t, 0, t, t, t}, {i, 1, L - 1}]}], 1] + 
      DiagonalMatrix[
       Flatten[{0, 0, t, 0, 0, 0, 
         Table[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {i, 1, L - 1}]}], 4] + 
      DiagonalMatrix[
       Flatten[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
         Table[{t, 0, 0, 0, t, 0, 0, 0}, {i, 1, L - 1}]}], 3] + 
      DiagonalMatrix[
       Flatten[{t, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
         Table[{0, 0, 0, t, 0, 0, 0, t}, {i, 1, L - 1}]}], 5] + 
      DiagonalMatrix[
       Flatten[{0, 0, 0, t, 
         Table[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {i, 1, L - 1}]}], 6];
    Energy = (wr + I*η)*
      DiagonalMatrix[
       Flatten[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
         Table[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {i, 1, L - 1}]}], 0];
    ];
   {Energy - (ConjugateTranspose[HH] + HH), U}
   ];
```

This is the main code for which I had to invest quite alot of time to refactor because of the extensive use of `Subscript` which completely obfuscated what was happening there. Also, the algorithm with `Subscript` required about 10 times more memory than actually needed. In general, `Subscript` is evil; it does not behave as you expect, and it should be generally avoided. A better option is using downvalues, e.g. `a[i]` instead of `Subscript[a,i]`. But even better is *not storing data that you don't need*.

After refactoring, it occured to me that this is actually a fixed point problem in disguise (hey, you could have told us, right?). So I recast the `Table` into a call to `FixedPoint`.

Notice also that variable scoping may be vital for letting this run in parallel.

```
Clear[cond2];
cond2[wr_, OptionsPattern[{
    "Tolerance" -> 1*^-12,
    "MaxIterations" -> 20
    }]] := Module[{
   a, b, c, d, A, B, AA, BB, CC, DD, U, UH, P, L, Energy, α, β, Pαβ, PAB, G0, G2, G11, ΣL, ΣR, ΓL, ΓR, F, residual, TOL, iter, maxiter, X, Y
   },
  TOL = OptionValue["Tolerance"];
  maxiter = OptionValue["MaxIterations"];
  {P, U} = getPandH[wr];
  UH = ConjugateTranspose[U];
  
  With[{S = LinearSolve[P]},
   With[{SU = S[U], SUH = S[UH]},
    α = B = UH.SU;
    β = A = U.SUH;
    
    Pαβ = P - α - β;
    PAB = P - A - B;
    
    a = BB = UH.SUH;
    b = AA = U.SU;
    c = d = 0.;
    CC = DD = 0.;
    ]
   ];
  
  F[{a_, b_, c_, d_, AA_, BB_, CC_, DD_}] := 
   Block[{Sαβ, S, sa, sb, SAA, SBB},
    Sαβ = LinearSolve[Pαβ - c];
    S = LinearSolve[PAB - CC];
    sa = Sαβ[a];
    sb = Sαβ[b];
    SAA = S[AA];
    SBB = S[BB];
    {a.sa, b.sb, c + a.sb + b.sa, d + b.sa, AA.SAA, BB.SBB, 
     CC + AA.SBB + BB.SAA, DD + BB.SAA}
    ];
  
  (*loop*)
  (*{a,b,c,d,AA,BB,CC,DD}=Nest[F,{a,b,c,d,AA,BB,CC,DD},
  s-1];*)
  residual = 1.;
  iter = 0;
  X = {a, b, c, d, AA, BB, CC, DD};
  While[residual > TOL && iter < maxiter,
   iter++;
   Y = F[X];
   residual = 
    Max[Abs[X[[4]] - Y[[4]]]]/Max[Abs[Y[[4]]]] + 
     Max[Abs[X[[8]] - Y[[8]]]]/Max[Abs[Y[[8]]]];
   X = Y;
   ];
  d = X[[4]];
  DD = X[[8]];
  (*---------------------------------------------------------------------\
*)
  G0 = LinearSolve[P - β - d];
  G2 = LinearSolve[P - B - DD];
  
  ΣL = U.G0[UH];
  ΣR = UH.G2[U];
  G11 = LinearSolve[P - ΣL - ΣR];
  ΓL = I (ΣL - ConjugateTranspose[ΣL]);
  ΓR = I (ΣR - ConjugateTranspose[ΣR]);
  Re[Tr[G11[ΓR].G11[ΓL, "J"]]]
  ]
```

This is not blazing much faster than the original implementation, though. We get a acceleration facto of about `4`, which roughly corresponds to the fact that the original code inverted each matrix four times.

For an argument close to `1.`:

```
cond[0.9] // RepeatedTiming
cond2[0.9] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.031, 1.99629}
>
> {0.0069, 1.99629}

For an argument close to `0.`:

> {0.030, 9.63865*10^-6}
>
> {0.0039, 9.63865*10^-6}

I leave the accuracy checks to the OP.

## Numerical Integration

Let's see what gives `NIntegrate` such a hard time:

```
n = 2000;
a = -1;
b = 1;
x = Subdivide[N[a], N[b], n];
vals = ParallelMap[cond2, x];

ListLinePlot[vals, DataRange -> {a, b}]
```

[image]

As we can see, the function has some extremely steep regions and probably  thesecause `NIntegrate` to adaptively refine around these regions forever.

However, we can apply [Tai's method](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9602/rediscovery-of-calculus-in-1994-what-should-have-happened-to-that-paper) to integrate it by hand:

```
ω = (b - a) ConstantArray[1./n, n + 1];
ω[[1]] *= 0.5;
ω[[-1]] *= 0.5;
ω.vals
```

> 2.17057

I tried the same with `n = 10000` and the difference of the two results was `-1.87783*10^-6`, so we may expect that the 5 leading digits are correct.

Comment: First of all, I would like to thanks for your dedication to this subject. I'm learning so much with this post. You got pretty accurate with this reformulation, now the results are calculated with lower computacional costs. How about this Tai's method, what a crazy story, a kind of one rediscovery of Riemann’s sum, very cool.

Comment: The original idea were to integrate cond[wr] using Riemann's sum, and plot mu vs sum1/(Te*sum).  With ```kt=kb*Te``` (kb=8.61*10^-5,Te=300).
 ```data[mu_]:=Module[{kt=0.02583,Te=300,sum=0,sum1=0},Do[sum = sum + (f[wr]*0.01); sum1 = sum1 + (f[wr]*(wr - mu)*0.01);, {wr,mu - 50*kt, mu + 50*kt, 0.01}]; sum1/(Te*sum)].
```
Where ```f[wr]=E^((wr - mu)/(kt))/(kt*((E^((wr - mu)/(kt)) + 1.)^2))*cond[wr]```
 Then use it as a function itself in a table ```ListLinePlot[Table[{mu,data[mu]},{mu,-0.4,0.4,0.1}]]```. Now with this Tai's method, what would you suggest to implement this?

Comment: Using the Riemann's sum above, for n=6 in getPandH[wr_] doing ```Table[{mu, data[mu]}, {mu, -2.5, 2.5, 0.1}];``` I got the results in 684.624 seconds.

Comment: Okay, let's look at the body of your function `data`: There the function `f[wr]` is called twice for each value of `wr`. Let's see what `f` does... ah! It calls `cond`! Might this be the most expensive computation around? Maybe we should some programming effort to prevent it from beeing called redundantly...

Comment: What about `data[mu_] := 
 Module[{kt = 0.02583, Te = 300., sum = 0., sum1 = 0., 
   kb = 8.61*10^-5, a},
  Do[
   a = E^((wr - mu)/(kt))/(kt ((E^((wr - mu)/(kt)) + 1.)^2)) cond[
      wr];
   sum = sum + (a 0.01);
   sum1 = sum1 + (a (wr - mu) 0.01);
   ,
   {wr, mu - 50*kt, mu + 50*kt, 0.01}
   ];
  sum1/(Te*sum)
  ]`? Then, with `n = 6`, the computation `ParallelMap[data, Subdivide[-2.5, 2.5, 50]]` takes about 20 seconds. At least on my Quad Core machine. However, removing the redundance and 4-times acceleration by `ParrallelMap` can explain only 8-fold speedup.

Comment: But notice that I used redefined `cond` to follow my implementation. Maybe you forgot the to dedefine `cond`? That would indeed explain the huge timing differences.

Comment: I'm already using your definition to cond. Indeed, not using Table and not calling f[wr] two times changes the computation time significantly. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You're welcome.