# Which algorithm would be better to integrate "step" like functions

Tags: numerical-integration

I have a function f[wr], in which the appearance is step like, first of all, the `NIntegrate` function is not handling this function, so I decided to do the integration algorithm by hand.

[image]

Without joined in plot

[image]

I have tried to integrate f[wr] using Riemann's sum

```
data[mu_] := 
 Module[{Te = 300., sum = 0., sum1 = 0., kb = 8.61*10^-5, a}, 
  Do[
   sum = sum + (f[wr] 0.01); 
   sum1 = sum1 + (f[wr] (wr - mu) 0.01);, {wr, mu - 30 kb Te, 
    mu + 30 kb Te, 0.01}]; sum1/(Te*sum)]
```

and then, evaluate it with

```
Table[{data[mu],{mu,-1,1}]
```

I think the results could be better if I try other algorithm. Could you suggest one?

edit: f[wr] algorithm https://pastebin.com/tfbGmhDa

ps: The part `Re[Tr[G11[ΓR].G11[ΓL, "J"]]]` in f[wr] is responsible for the step like results

Comment: I think the best approach is to use `NIntegrate`, but to let it know where the discontinuities are. We could try and explain how this works, but it would be helpful if you could share your definition of `f` (or to come up with a qualitatively similar function; the simpler the better).

Comment: `Integrate` might work, depending on `f[w]`. Please include its definition.

Comment: The algorithm to get f[wr] is in the pastebin. How can I use NIntegrate on this kind of function?

Comment: Is `f` supposed to return a numerical value? If so, what is `mu`? I tried a few different values of `mu` between 0.1 and 2, and I'm getting a sharp peak, rather than a step-type plot.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the question! `Integrate` and `NIntegrate` can handle step-function!?!

Comment: @MelaGo Sorry about that. I forgot to say that the part ```Re[Tr[G11[ΓR].G11[ΓL, "J"]]]``` in function of wr is step like function, without ```*E^((wr - mu)/(kb Te))/(kb Te ((E^((wr - mu)/(kb Te)) + 1.)^2))```. But the integration values of the whole thing f[wr] in terms of mu, where wr is between `` mu - 30 kb Te and mu + 30 kb Te```, we hope another result, more like https://imgur.com/U41zVWA

Comment: @UlrichNeumann the NIntegrate isn't returning nothing for this f[wr]

Comment: @LucasLopes Unfortunately I cannot access the link. Perhaps you can provide the data points directly?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann the **b3m2a1** linked the previous post with the code definitions

Answer (score 1):

Just a note. This is gonna be a tough function to integrate. Using [Henrik's answer to your previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/203563/38205) we have this:

```
ListLinePlot[
 Table[{wr, cond2[wr]}, {wr, -10, 10, .05}]
 ]
```

[image]

You're going to need a huge number of sampling points to even get close to an okay result. The fact, then, that your function is so slow is doing you a big disservice. On the other hand this function is *basically* piecewise constant so I'd go back to your original model, figure out where that's coming from, and use that as an ansatz for your integration.

Comment: As you may notice, the cond2[wr] is obtained from a recursive method, where the number of steps is given by **s=20**. It's like a FoldList applied to a function, for each step, I get something like F[..F[...[F(wr)]]]. At the end, I need to get this F[..F[..F(wr)]] and integrate it with other terms which I called f[wr] in this post, but essentially the problematic functions is cond2[wr], and I can't escape from the recursive method to obtain it.

Comment: Cool but there might be some recursion relation to exploit to figure out where that piece wise constant nature is coming from. That’s my real suggestion. If the numerical method is working poorly you might want to go back and look at the math.

Answer (score 0):

Given a function composed by unit steps, $f(t)$ You can produce a function such as

$$
S(t) = \int_0^t f(\tau)d\tau
$$

Follows script

```
Clear[t, k, s, f, S]
ustep = Sum[(-1)^k HeavisideTheta[t - RandomInteger[{0, 15}]], {k, 1, 25}];
f[t_] := ustep
ltustep = LaplaceTransform[f[t], t, s];
intustep = InverseLaplaceTransform[ltustep/s, s, t];
S[t_] := intustep  
Plot[{f[t], S[t]}, {t, 0, 15}, PlotRange -> All]
```